# MS Teams Integration & Microsoft Graph API - Error calling Events API List calendars (/me/calendars)

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to integrate the MS Teams API in a Web-App.
First of all i was trying to use the MS API from Postman to see the workflow.

On the Azure UI i have succesfully created an App-Registration: i have my **ClientID**, **TenantID** and i have created also the **client secret**.

I downloaded the Postman API from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoftgraph-postman-collections and i can retrieve the **App-Only Access token**.

I created two users in a group and i logged them on MS Teams Application, they can chat.

I can also get the **User Access Token** and endpoints such

1. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
2. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
3. etc..

are correctly working.

I am passing the User Access Token as Bearer token for the request.

These are the API permissions i gave:
[image]

I am having issues with the endpoints in the folder **Events** like:

1. https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms
2. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars
3. etc..

They all give the same error:

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":"NoUserFoundWithGivenClaims",
      "message":"The user specified by the user-context in the token does not exist.",
      "innerError":{
         "oAuthEventOperationId":"08e3abc3-3fdf-4d85-849d-7632ac0723d2",
         "oAuthEventcV":"CGW24oLIeEW1qoscgMIMTw.1.1",
         "errorUrl":"https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidUser",
         "requestId":"8e6cb242-17fe-4a94-8c89-912606578fb3",
         "date":"2021-03-09T12:04:27"
      }
   }
}
```

I haven't found anything about this error.
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling the  /findRoom and /calendar API's using App only access token?

Comment: Hi @ShivaKeshavVarma thanks for the answer.
No, i am calling it passing these: 
ClientID, ClientSecret, TenantID, AppAccessToken, UserPassword & UserName (of the current user), UserAccessToken, UserId, TeamId, SiteId.

Should i only pass the App only access token?

Comment: Check your bearer token by putting it in https://jwt.ms and see if you have the required permissions in 'scp' claim.

Comment: You were right, only passing the Token the API is working.
But now there is one other problem, the api response with this error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI",
        "message": "REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox."
    }
}

Comment: Check if you have proper exchange license added to the users which you are logging in with.

Comment: No i haven't the license, i think this is the problem.
How can i add it? I went int Azure Active Directory > Licenses but when i go in "All products" i can't find Exchange or MS 365 option to add.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it so that it could be helpful to others.

Comment: It was, i accepted it!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your bearer token by putting it in jwt.ms and see if you have the required permissions in 'scp' claim.

If you are getting `MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI` then you need to check if you have the proper exchange license or not.

You can add license by going into [Microsoft Admin Center](https://admin.microsoft.com) -> Users -> Active Users -> Select your user -> Licenses